# Rails removing 's' off the word business as it thinks it is a plural?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

```
Category.where(:name => params[:category]).joins(:business)
```

Gets me:

```
uninitialized constant Category::Busines
```

Why does it keep on missing an s off business or not detecting the model? I am sure it is me messing up here. : (

Comment: It looks to me like the call to Category.where... etc generates the successful Category Load (56.4 ms) in the log, so how does your code before and after Category.where... look like? Because I think the error is generated by something else.

Comment: You would think it would be the case but well there is nowhere else in my code that references these two models at all, it was just that one line :|

Comment: Do you have a line in your Category model that defines the relationship (e.g. has_many etc.) between Category and Business? If so, what's that line?

Comment: I have: has_and_belongs_to_many :businesses, :join_table => "businesses_categories" and vice versa in the Business model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to specify the same name as the relation, in this case `:businesses`.

```
Category.where(:name => params[:category]).joins(:businesses)
```

Answer (score 1):

It ended up being that the pluralization of businesses had not been applied everywhere across my models and also the join needed to state

```
joins(:businesses)
```

Thank you for the comments as it made me look again in a different light at what I had written.